# Eval inside an ASP.net repeater doesn't work inside another control

Tags: asp.net, community-server, telligent

I have a Reapter control with a custom server side control inside of it. When I place the code:

```
<%# Eval("DateAdded") %>
```

inside the item template of the repeater it works fine, but when I place it inside the custom server control inside the repeater, it doesn't work.
Is it possible to do something like Parent.Eval() or Container.Eval() to get back to the context of the Reapeter rather than the custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeater is databound, the control that you are placing this eval statement in isn't.  You'll need to pass the value to the control using a property.

For Example:

```
<uc1:MyControl MyProperty='<%# Eval("DateAdded") %>' />
```

You can now access the `MyProperty` property inside your control to access this value.

Comment: Does this require that MyProperty be defined as a property before hand or can it just be done on the fly? I don't have access to the source code of the custom control so I can't go adding properties to it.

Comment: Yeah, it would need to be a property on the control.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Can you supply more context/code for the server control?

Also, are you using single quotes to set properties on a control dynamically using eval? Double quotes should throw an error, not just be ignored.

```
MyProperty='<%# Eval("DateAdded") %>'
```